# change text color of UIBarButtonItem in UIImagePickerController?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I use **native** `UIImagePickerController` in of **my** view controller.

I use a different color for `UIBarButtonItem` than what iPhone uses `UIImagePickerController`

is it possible for me to change textColor of `UIImagePickerController.UIBarButtonItem` ??

I tried

```
UIImagePickerController *picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
picker.delegate = self;
picker.allowsEditing = YES;
picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
picker.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem.tintColor = [UIColor redColor];
for (UIBarButtonItem *item in picker.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems) {
    item.tintColor = [UIColor redColor];
}
for (UIView *view in picker.navigationBar.subviews) {
    NSLog(@"%@", [[view class] description]);
    if ([[[view class] description] isEqualToString:@"UIBarButtonItem"]) {
        [(UIBarButtonItem *)view setTintColor:[UIColor redColor]];
    }
}
[self presentViewController:picker animated:YES completion:NULL];
```

Output of NSlog was

```
_UINavigationBarBackground
_UINavigationBarBackIndicatorView
```

**EDIT 2:
I needed to do**

```
picker.navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor redColor];
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to change the color of UIBarButtonItem?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3360856/how-to-change-the-color-of-uibarbuttonitem)

Comment: tintColor should do the job. What happened when you used tintColor ?